# Jspresso 4.1-SNAPSHOT flex client ist working but html5 client is not

Tags: java, qooxdoo, jspresso

I have done the 5min CRUD tutorial and the flex client ist perfectly working but after login to the html5 client the screen ist empty. In the browser console i see the following error two times:
TypeError:bf is null
/helloworld-webapp/html5/script/com.example.helloworld.startup.qooxdoo.js(Line 210)

Any hints?

**UPDATE:**
After starting from scratch as Vincent suggested both clients are working like a charm now. I had to update my local maven cache what i have done with mvn package -U. Doing this in eclipse i had to refresh the project tree (F5) afterwards otherwise the compiled clients were not found at the next deployment to tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was actually a problem regarding the new qooxdoo theme in 4.1-SNAPSHOT that was not correctly installed in the application generated from the archetype.
It should be fixed by now. Could you please try again from scratch ?